# How to bind multiple data frames together automatically and to differentiate them based on a new column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have the following list of data frames. I would like to add all 178 data frames into one.

[image]

The following code merge the first two data frames together:

```
 df =bind_rows(mysheets$AU81,mysheets$AT95)
```

However, the resulting new data frame `df` does not differentiate between `AU81` and `AT95`. I would like to do two things. First, i would like to bind all data frames together without manually inserting the name of each one. Second, i would like to create a new variable (`country_name`) that differentiates all these binded data_frames in the new one created. Then the data frame should look something like this:

[image]

Could someone help please?

Comment: `bind_rows(mysheets)`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, that solves the automatic vs manual issue. But do you have any idea how to include the names of the datasheets inside the newly created data frame so i can differentiate between them?

Comment: `bind_rows(mysheets,.id = "country_name")` should add a column with labels using the names of the list of dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers of @ekolima and @Maël in the comments, this line of code solves the issue:

```
bind_rows(mysheets,.id = "country_name")
```